# Python Flask local server not updating

Tags: python, http, flask, request

I am starting to learn Flask, so I am a noob in this stuff, but I have ran out of ideas to implement, that is why I came here to ask. I have python script that makes a GET request to the API and it returns me a QRcode, after that I get the QRcode and add it to my html, everything works fine.

But I have this code checking for the JSON response that the API gives me, it haves three responses: "loading", "authenticated" & "got qr code".

```
req = requests.get('this is the link with my API token')
json_content = req.content

# parsed JSON content, ready to use
parsed_json = json.loads(json_content)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if parsed_json["accountStatus"] == "loading":
        print(parsed_json["accountStatus"])
        print(req.status_code)
        return render_template("loading.html")

    if parsed_json["accountStatus"] == "got qr code":
        print(parsed_json["accountStatus"])
        str_parsed_json = yaml.safe_load(parsed_json["qrCode"])
        print(req.status_code)
        return render_template("qrcodePage.html", str_parsed_json=str_parsed_json)

    if parsed_json["accountStatus"] == "authenticated":
        print(parsed_json["accountStatus"])
        print(req.status_code)
        return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
```

The response I am getting is a `200`

I have searched all over the internet to see if someone else has the same issue as me, but I haven't found one person with this problem. 
I have tried restarting the following

1. Restart my local server
2. Making True the debug thing in the app.run()
3. Check in PostMan the server response but it always return me the expected result, but changes are not seen in the page.

The only way it seems to work is when I make some changes to my code, and restart the server, that is when I can refresh the page and redirect me to the expected template file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question adding the output that you are getting when running the script. Also, have you verified if `req.status_code` is `200`?

Comment: Maybe move your `req`, `json_content` and `parse_json` inside your `def index()`? As it stands your `request` will only `GET` *once* when the server starts.

Comment: @Idlehands is right, those lines should be inside your `index` function. And also I would check for the request status before attempting to parse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `requests.get` and all subsequent object based on that inside your `index()`:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    req = requests.get('this is the link with my API token')
    json_content = req.content

    # parsed JSON content, ready to use
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_content)
    if parsed_json["accountStatus"] == "loading":
        print(parsed_json["accountStatus"])
        return render_template("loading.html")

    ... rest of your code
```

Currently your `requests` is not being refreshed past the point of your server starting.  But if you move it inside your `@app.route("/")` each time you visit the site's root page, it will do a new `requests.get()` to refresh your data.